# What is is the difference between ArrayList.get(int index) and ArrayAdapter.getItem(int position) methods?

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am setting up an `OnItemClickListener` and I can't see the difference between the two methods and they both work just fine, and I can't understand the difference between them from the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined on different classes - that is the only difference.

The adapter method calls the other.

[`ArrayAdapter<T>` Android Source code.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L348)

```
public T getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position);
}
```

---

You actually don't "need" to store an Arraylist independently in your class.

ArrayAdapter has its own `add()` method and you call the constructor that doesn't take a list.

```
public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
    this(context, resource, 0, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that the adapter is better suitable to display information in the UI. Therefore, if you have to display list in ListView for example, you can use only the adapter.

The main advantage is that you don't have to manage both the list and the adapter, and the UI will be updated as the array is updated. However you may have to call to

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

at some point to refresh the UI.